# Android - storing folders in main storage is unsafe?

Tags: android, directory, delete-directory, android-storage

In the past there was no problem store application settings in folder located directly in main storage.

F.e : `/storage/emulate/0/MyFolder`

But now, I fight war with **clean master**, **ccleaner** or with device updates. They all have attempt to clean up main storage, result is deleted "**MyFolder**".

Yes, I know, Google recommends store all settings in private folder. But this is big trouble for me. In my application people creates many custom documents and they don't understand that application uninstall means "erase all documents". They think, that everything works like on Windows OS and documents will stay there. And android does not offer "`onUninstall`" event in which I can offer backup/export functionality.

That's why I store everything in "**MyFolder**" in main storage. Is there any way how to store settings in folder which will survive uninstall?

I was thinking about moving "**MyFolder**" to "Downloads", but I am not sure. Offers android something like "path registration" which can survive all cleaning processes?

Comment: well thats where the server hits the game i think

Comment: I solved this issue. I did two fixes. First, I added dot at beginning of folder name. Seems, cleaners skips folders starting with dot. In addition, I let user choose location for saving all settings - 1. to private folder 2. or to public folder. And of course people can do backup to shared services.